# Android - How to edit button string

Tags: android, button

I would ask you a quick question.

In my layout, I have added a button with text "Go to store":

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/go_to_store"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go to store"/>
```

I got the details from Json response:

```
JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);
            JSONArray couponCategoryArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < couponCategoryArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject currentEarthquake = couponCategoryArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject properties = currentEarthquake.getJSONObject("campaign");
                String name = properties.getString("name");

                String promo_code = currentEarthquake.getString("promocode");

                String goto_store = currentEarthquake.getString("goto_link");

                CouponCategory couponCategory = new CouponCategory(name, promo_code, goto_store);
                couponcategory.add(couponCategory);

            }
```

and

```
Button descriptionTextView = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.go_to_store);
    descriptionTextView.setText(currentCouponCategory.getDescription());
    descriptionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(currentCouponCategory.getDescription()));
            getContext().startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
```

And the coupon Category is:

```
private String mStoreName;

private String mPromoCode;

private String mGotoStore;

public CouponCategory(String storeName, String promoCode, String gotoStore) {
    mStoreName = storeName;
    mPromoCode = promoCode;
    mGotoStore = gotoStore;
}

//** Get the Magnitude of the earthquake*/
public String getStoreName() { return mStoreName; }

public String getPromoCode() { return mPromoCode; }

public String getDescription() { return mGotoStore; }}
```

JSON response:

```
\"image\":\"http://cdn.admitad.com/campaign/images/2015/03/13/26eb60d1e6b5d4ec7c92062e5d1e8430.jpg\",\n" +
        "         \"species\":\"promocode\",\n" +
        "         \"categories\":[\n" +
        "            {\n" +
        "               \"id\":8,\n" +
        "               \"name\":\"Компьютеры и электроника\"\n" +
        "            }\n" +
        "         ],\n" +
        "         \"name\":\"Banggood 10% OFF Site Wide Coupon\",\n" +
        "         \"promocode\":\"BGAFF10OFF\",\n" +
        "         \"frameset_link\":\"\",\n" +
        "         \"goto_link\":\"https://ad.admitad.com/g/tx4zgk4gbq2e4b3978f86213826a88/?i=3\"\n" +
```

I am trying to edit part of the code but I continue to see, in the button, the link of the store got from Json: https://ibb.co/ZTQkwH5

How could I fix it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please don't link to your code as off-site resources or images, please include everything relevant as text in your question, only use images to describe what you can't describe with text

Comment: I edit immediately, sorry.

Comment: no problem :) the reason why it's bad is because it doesn't help others who might have the same problem in future, as the code won't be searchable to them, as well as links and resources changing, if someone in future has the same problem as you and the link has changed, then they won't get an answer. that's why it's best to include everything here

Comment: You are right. I changed it.

Comment: @MrPlunk where is currentCouponCategory

Comment: I added it also.

Comment: can you also post up json response n what exactly you want to display on button???

Comment: so if you want to display store name on button then why are are you fetching description??

Comment: I added part of the JSON response because is so long. On the button, I would to show "Go to store" with hyper link to store url.

Comment: then use this --> `descriptionTextView.setText(currentCouponCategory.getStoreName());`

Comment: Thank you Wini. I tried it and, in this case, I read the sstore name on the button. But, on the button I would to show "Go to store".

Comment: then make it go to store `descriptionTextView.setText("Go to store")`

Comment: Wow, solved it. Thank you for your answer. I tried different ways but not this. Thank you Wini

Comment: Yes, you can do it, sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this-->

```
descriptionTextView.setText("Go to store")
```

instead of -->

```
descriptionTextView.setText(currentCouponCategory.getStoreName());
```